# How to deploy packages installed by Bower?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, bower

I have installed a few packages using Bower, but I don't know how to deploy them.

For example, my first idea was to create a Gulp task that will concatenate them - I did this with my angular packages:

```
gulp.task('libs', function () {
    'use strict';
    return gulp
        .src([
            './public/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js',
            './public/assets/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
            './public/assets/libs/angular-routes/angular-route.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'));
});
```

However, while these packages above are quite simple, some others (Bootstrap and jQuery, to be precise) come with sources which I don't need. Should I just copy `bootstrap.min.css` and `jquery.min.js` to my `dist` folder?

Frankly, I could just include all of these files from a CDN, I do not yet understand why I would use Bower (I've been following a tutorial that is using Bower).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here's the reason for using Bower, in my opinion.

In "the old days", the way to include a particular JavaScript library (let's say jQuery) in your application would be to go to the jQuery website, click the download link, and move the downloaded `.zip` file into your project directory and unzip it. Then you would add a `script` tag that includes the library.

The "modern" way of including a JavaScript library (still using jQuery as an example) is to simply run `bower install jquery --save`, which will a) add jQuery to your `bower.json` file which lists all your application's dependencies and b) grab the jQuery files and put them in the appropriate place. And if you're using something called injection, which you may or may not have already encountered, you don't even have to worry about the `script` tags as this is taken care of by your build system.

(By the way, I assume Bower was inspired by other languages' package management tools like RubyGems for Ruby, which I understand existed years prior to anything like that in the JavaScript world. It may be interesting for you to take a look at tools like that as well.)

Second, I'll answer your question about deployment.

It depends to where you're deploying. I personally use Heroku for all my production environments. I don't check my JavaScript vendor libraries into Git because it's not a good idea to keep build artifacts in version control. Instead, I just check in my `bower.json`, which Heroku is able to detect. Heroku runs a `bower install` on production which pulls in all the appropriate library files. That's how my deployment works, although it's not the only way it could be done.

If you'd like to know how to deploy to a specific platform, it may be a good idea to edit this question or create a separate one that includes more detail about your deployment environment.

Comment: I think you answered my question: in essence, the whole bower_components structure is going to be there on the server as well. By the way, I used to use RubyGems and I also currently use NPM of course, but while not uploading `node_modules` and running `npm install` on the server seemed straightforward, the same didn't with Bower.

Comment: If I understand everything right, should I just point to my `bower_components` directory when including certain files in my views?